Column comparison between rows of the same group used in Partition By clause
I want to compare same columns of rows falling into the same group created by partition by clause in SQL. My table has below data:
Id  Serial_Number   Last_update_date    Flag
1   3344            07-05-2024          N
2   3344            02-05-2024          N
3   9098            20-02-2024          Y
4   9098            20-02-2024          Y
5   2323            07-03-2023          Y
6   2323            17-10-2023          Y
7   2323            17-10-2023          Y
8   1894            10-07-2022          N
9   1894            20-02-2024          N
10  1894            02-05-2024          N

In the above data, grouping should be done by Serial_Number column and should check if any 2 dates within a serial_number are same, the flag for all the group members should be Y, otherwise all should be N.
I tried using count(distinct last_update_date) over partition by serial_number but it is not working.
with cte as (
  select a.*, count(distinct last_update_date) 
                   over (partition by serial_number) as cnt
  from my_table a
)
select * from cte 


Maybe we could use this fiddle to collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/rRvXt-uM

Something like: select case when max(cnt) over(partition by serialnumber) > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, * FROM (select *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Serial_number, last_update_date) AS cnt FROM yourtable) x

@siggemannen why are you calculating Flag? Flag is already part of the initial data.

@BartMcEndree i read it that flag is the expected value he's looking for :)

@Mohammed Arif please clarify your initial data and expected results as separate tables.

If any 2 dates in partition is equal then max(dense_rank()) < count(*) for this partition.
with cte as (
  select a.*
    ,dense_rank()over (partition by serial_number order by last_update_date) as rnk
  from my_table a
)
select * 
  ,case when max(rnk)over(partition by serial_number)
               < count(*)over(partition by serial_number) 
       then 'Y' 
   else 'N' 
   end flag
from cte 
order by id




Id
Serial_Number
Last_update_date
rnk
flag
max_rnk
cnt




1
3344
2024-05-07
2
N
2
2


2
3344
2024-05-02
1
N
2
2


3
9098
2024-02-20
1
Y
1
2


4
9098
2024-02-20
1
Y
1
2


5
2323
2023-03-07
1
Y
2
3


6
2323
2023-10-17
2
Y
2
3


7
2323
2023-10-17
2
Y
2
3


8
1894
2022-07-10
1
N
3
3


9
1894
2024-02-20
2
N
3
3


10
1894
2024-05-02
3
N
3
3



demo

WITH CTE as
(
SELECT Serial_number, count(*) as DateCount
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Serial_number, Last_update_date
HAVING Count(*) > 1  
)
SELECT m.*, 
  CASE WHEN DateCount > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as CalculatedFlag
FROM my_table m
LEFT JOIN CTE on CTE.Serial_number=m.Serial_number

fiddle



Id
Serial_Number
Last_update_date
Flag
CalculatedFlag




1
3344
07-05-2024
N
N


2
3344
02-05-2024
N
N


3
9098
20-02-2024
Y
Y


4
9098
20-02-2024
Y
Y


5
2323
07-03-2023
Y
Y


6
2323
17-10-2023
Y
Y


7
2323
17-10-2023
Y
Y


8
1894
10-07-2022
N
N


9
1894
20-02-2024
N
N


10
1894
02-05-2024
N
N



